# Need help with proving $x_n = (−1)^n (n^2 + 3) / (n^2 + 5n − 1)$ is NOT a Cauchy sequence using only definition

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

The Cauchy Sequence is that: $\forall \epsilon > 0 \,\,\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall m>n \ge n_0 \,\,|x_m - x_n| \le \epsilon$. Let's negate it, we will get ∃>0 ∀0∈ℕ  such that ∃>≥0 |−|≥.

I have tried to estimate it from above, but could not take it to the end.

Comment: It is not a Cauchy sequence because it doesn't converge.

Comment: @Gribouillis yes, thank you. I made a typo.

Comment: Hint: estimate $|x_n - (-1)^n|$ from above by a quantity that tends to $0$.

Comment: What you wrote in the body of the post is definition of Cauchy sequence. But in the title you say you are to show it is *not* a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: @coffeemath yes, we can use the negation of it

Answer (score 0):

Well, we can *feel* that $x_{2k} \to 1$ while $x_{2k + 1} \to -1$ so for a large enough $N$ if we have $n > N; n$ even and $m > N; m$ odd we should have

$|x_n - x_m| \approx 2>  \epsilon$ for a small epsilon.

Let's get that in detail.

Let $\epsilon > 0$.  Suppose $2k, 2k+ 1 > N$. with

$|x_{2k} - x_{2k+1}| < \epsilon$.

That means $|\frac {(2k)^2+3}{(2k)^2+ 5(2k) + 1} -(-\frac {(2k+1)^2+3}{(2k+1)^2+ 5(2k+1) + 1})| =$

$|\frac {4k^2 + 3}{4k^2 + 10k + 1} + \frac {4k^2 + 4k +4}{4k^2 + 14k + 7}|< \epsilon$.

But $\frac {4k^2 + 4k + 4}{4k^2 + 14k +7} > \frac {4k^2 +3}{4k^2 + 14k +7}$ and $\frac {4k^2 + 3}{4k^2 + 10k + 1} > \frac {4k^2 +3}{4k^2 + 14k +7}$ so (assuming $k > \frac {N}2 > 0$) we have

$2\frac {4k^2 +3}{4k^2 + 14k +7} < |\frac {4k^2 + 3}{4k^2 + 10k + 1} + \frac {4k^2 + 4k +4}{4k^2 + 14k + 7}|< \epsilon$

So $\epsilon$ must be larger than $2\frac {4k^2 +3}{4k^2 + 14k +7}=2(1 - \frac {14k+4}{4k^2+14k + 7})> 2(1-\frac {14k}{4k^2}) = 2- \frac {14}{k}$.

So if $k > 14$ then $\epsilon > 1$ .

so for any $\epsilon < 1$  we can't have an $N$ where $n, m > N$ imply $|x_n - x_m| < \epsilon$ as taking any $2k, 2k+1 > \max(N, 28)$ we have $|x_n - x_m| > \epsilon$.

SO not cauchy.